# Search in splunk doesn't sum()

Tags: splunk

I have this search in Splunk, and the field `value` it shows in the graphic, is just the biggest and not the sum of each one.

```
host=users| JOIN type=inner id [ SEARCH host=bills | rename id_user AS id ] | stats sum(value) as value by document | sort - value | head 20
```

value has this format `2000.0`

Maybe it has to be with the `sort - value`
I'm new using Splunk

This is the result without the `stats`

[image]

Comment: Could you include some events that are shown if you run just the search with the inner join and subsearch, without the stats command?

Comment: Done! it show the same like the stats weren't used.

Comment: I'm not certain what's going on yet, as I don't know what's in the events.  If you remove the join, can you sum value by document? That would help determine if the problem is caused by the join/subsearch or not. Also, what relevant fields are coming from which index?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the same name for the sum and the field:
   stats sum(value) as value by document | sort - value
maybe if you change the name of the sum field:
    stats sum(value) as value1 by document | sort - value1